# How do I deal with pandas not being able to read type 'WindowsPath' from pathlib?

Tags: pandas, typeerror, pathlib

I'm trying to read .html files into pd.read_html(). However each .html file is within a different directory. So I've iterated over each directory and put the `path/name` + `html_file_name` in a list called `html_paths`. I want to iterate over this list and read each .html file in `html_paths` with pd.read_html()

I've tried to iterate over the html_paths like this:

```
for I in range(len(html_paths)):
     html_files = pd.read_html(html_paths[i])
```

I also tried to glob the original html_paths I set up with this:

```
for I in path.glob('**/*.html'):
     html_files = pd.read_html(i)
```

Any way I try to iterate over my path lib list I get an error similar to `TypeError: Cannot read object type 'WindowsPAth'`

So far I've written:

```
# initialize path
p = Path('C:\path\to\mother\directory')

# iterate over all directories within mother directory
# glob all html files
html_paths = [file for file in p.glob('**/*.html')
```

And now I want to iterate over each file in `html_paths` and read them into `pd.read_html()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `html_paths` list contains Path objects, not strings like `read_html` is expecting. Try converting it to a string:

```
for I in range(len(html_paths)):
    html_files = pd.read_html(str(html_paths[I]))
```

Comment: It looks like that is now resulting in a `ValueError` that says "no tables found"

Comment: Are you sure the HTML file you are trying to parse has a table in it? I'm not a pandas user. It sounds like your first problem has been resolved and you have a new error/question to work through.

Comment: Oh wait, I see that I can use pd.read_html() if I cast html_paths as a string one index at a time (e.g. pd.read_html(str(html_paths[0])) gives me the result I want). However, when I try and iterate over them like in your example it throws the "No tables found" error.

Comment: And kind of, part of my problem was resolved in that I now know to cast the html_paths as a string in order to read it into the pd.read_html() function. But the main point of my question was to get to the point where I could iterate over each file and read it into pandas. Also, I'm sure each html file has a table in it. I can read them individually, just having problems iterating over them.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, the loop variable `I` was capitalized in the `for I in` part but not in the `html_paths[I]` part. I fixed it in the answer.